# Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class (referring to different workbook)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to use VLookup in VBA code to lookup values from a different workbook (Excel 2010 VBA). I'm getting the error above on the last line of the code below:

```
Sub GetFundValues(Source As String, Target As String, wb As Workbook)
    Dim nIdx As Integer
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceFile As Workbook
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim s3 As String
    Dim rng As Range


    s2 = wb.Sheets(Target).Range("C2").Value

    Set SourceFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\Mydocs\Finance\inv.xls")
    Set SourceSheet = SourceFile.Worksheets(Source)

    s3 = SourceSheet.Range("A3").Value
    Set rng = SourceSheet.Range("A3:A30")

    nIdx = 3

    With wb.Sheets(Target)
        While wb.Sheets(Target).Range("H" & nIdx).Value <> ""
            s2 = wb.Sheets(Target).Range("H" & nIdx).Value
            wb.Sheets(Target).Range("B" & nIdx).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(s2, rng, 3, False)
```

The values of the s2, s3 and rng variables are set correctly (they are there for debugging purposes), and the value column in the Vlookup (column #3) contains valid values.

I can't think what other problem in the VLookup might be causing this. Any ideas??

Comment: You have declared s2 as a string, are you looking up numbers by any chance? If so, try declaring s2 as a numerical data type.

Comment: The lookup search item is a string, and the value being returned is a number. So presumably this code is OK?

Answer (score 2):

Just spotted this:

```
Set rng = SourceSheet.Range("A3:A30")
```

The range you are looking in is only 1 column wide. As you are trying to return data from the 3rd column, your range needs to be at least 3 columns wide:

```
Set rng = SourceSheet.Range("A3:C30")
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks - that explains it